# XSS Protection - is it safe for someone to be able to create an exploit that only they can see?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

Long story short, I have a web app that has amongst other things, lets users (who have to be logged in) create, deploy and receive submissions from online forms, using a JSON framework for data storage.

At the point a user saves their newly created form, various checks are run to prevent SQL injection and to catch potential XSS exploits.

However, when creating the actual form, any code entered into fields is rendered in real time on the users browser. So, if I decided to type the following into a paragraph field:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert(1);">click me</a>
```

... it would in immediately display the link and run the JS if clicked. However, if the user attempted to save this form, the code would be ripped apart by my existing safeguards and cease to function on the deployed form. So the only person that could ever run the code, would be the person that created it.

So, my question is, what risk exists in allowing users to dynamically create content in real time, including JS, provided they can't deploy it or save it to my DB? I sense there is probably a risk, but I'm not an XSS expert.

To clarify, only the person generating the code would ever be able to run it. The moment they saved the data, it would be torn apart.

Comment: if your cleanup works it's safe as described.

Comment: That's reassuring. I've been throwing XSS cheatsheet examples at it for weeks now, and am yet to find anything that can get through. But always that worry I'm overlooking something.

Comment: I guess your case is comparable to pressing F12 and typing javascript into the browser console. It only gives you access to what you already have, and other entities are not affected by it.

Comment: @Flame There are potential attacks, and it's not directly comparable to the dev console. It depends on what you want to secure your application against, and the tool to find out is threat modeling. Interestingly, Facebook for example even found the dev console as a potential threat, see their console for the mitigation. :)

Comment: @GaborLengyel in both cases user A is running code which he himself has entered. Judging by the tags of this post, I think the user input is just somehow eval'd or inserted into the DOM, which causes it to execute. It's not stated that any of the user input is sent to the server. The threat level therefore seems to be the same as dev console input.

Comment: @Flame see my answer for a potential attack vector (unsuspecting user copypasting). There are surely more ways for an attacker to exploit this.

Comment: Yes, the unfiltered data is never stored on the server. It's entered dynamically into the DOM client side. Any attempt to save the data causes the full range of XSS and SQL injections to come into play.

Comment: @GaborLengyel same attack vector as copypasting it in some user interface that parses the javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Whether that is a risk in your case depends on your exact usecase and your threat model.

What immediately comes to mind is what if an attacker sends a legitimate user a piece of text to copy-paste in the field. It might not be easy to spot code in a larger chunk of text, and that way an attacker could exploit this against an unsuspecting user. Also while I think much less likely, limited control of the client computer can help exploit this. So there are attack vectors that could be possible - or not, it depends on your application, and who uses it and how.

In professional penetration tests, this *is* usually considered valid XSS.

Also in addition to that, please note that checks "to prevent SQL injection and to catch potential XSS exploits" on the input side are probably not effective enough, especially for such complex user input. To prevent SQL injection, you need parameterized queries in some way, and to prevent XSS you need output encoding, or if HTML is a requirement, then a proven sanitization solution (eg. Google Caja, but there are others).

In your usecase, a Javascript html sanitizer (eg. HTML Purifier or the pure Javascript part of Caja) could help prevent XSS. This would have to be integrated with your UI code so that anything entered in the input field gets properly sanitized before added to the DOM. Note that this is only necessary if displaying user-supplied HTML input is a requirement. Otherwise you can simply output encode whatever the user entered (or simply assign it to the DOM as a text node).